# How not to alter duplicate names with sapply?

Tags: r, apply, sapply, agrep

I have a text vector with the names of drugs already registered, and another with the names of new drugs. I want to know whether the new drugs look like an already existing drug or not.

For example, if supercure is a drug which can be producted either by firm1 or firm2, and `supercure firm1 1000mg` and `supercure firm2 500mg` are already registered, then `supercure firm1 500 mg` should be associated with both of them.

`agrep` allows to do such matching in R, and `sapply` allows to do it for every drug in the new list :

```
new<-c("supercure firm1 500mg","randomcure firm2 1000mg","unknowncure firm2 100mg")
registered<-c("supercure firm1 1000mg","supercure firm2 500mg","randomcure firm1 1000mg")
res<-unlist(sapply(new,agrep,x=registered))
res
```

As expected, supercure gets two matches, randomcure one match and unknowncure no match (which is what I want). However, `sapply` appears to have altered the names so that there is no duplicate : `supercure firm1 500mg` became `supercure firm1 500mg1` and `supercure firm1 500mg2` :

```
supercure firm1 500mg1   supercure firm1 500mg2 randomcure firm2 1000mg 
                    1                       2                       3
```

This is a problem because it prevents me to select matched drugs from the new list :

`new[new %in% names(res)]` only catches randomcure (because supercure's name has been altered).

I can think of ways of fixing this by quite graceless text processing, but is there a more clever way of getting the list of new drugs who found a match ?

The ideal output would be :

```
supercure firm1 500mg   supercure firm1 500mg randomcure firm2 1000mg 
                    1                       2                       3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sapply` didn't alter the name, `unlist` did. This gives the desired output:

```
x <- sapply(new,agrep,x=registered)
setNames(unlist(x),rep(names(x),lengths(x)))
#  supercure firm1 500mg   supercure firm1 500mg randomcure firm2 1000mg 
#                      1                       2                       3
```

Comment: Indeed, my bad. Nice solution here !

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make it a data frame , `stack` it and use `setNames` to make it a named vector, i.e.

```
d1 <- unique(stack(data.frame(Filter(length, sapply(new,agrep,x=registered)))))
#  values                     ind
#1      1   supercure.firm1.500mg
#2      2   supercure.firm1.500mg
#3      3 randomcure.firm2.1000mg

setNames(d1$values, d1$ind)
#  supercure.firm1.500mg   supercure.firm1.500mg randomcure.firm2.1000mg 
#                      1                       2                       3
```